# How can I list the plugins currently *active* when using VIM-Plug?

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-vim-plug

Oftentimes I'll want to put remaps in my `.vimrc` that use plugin commands. When a plugin happens to not be installed, these remaps will result in errors. A simple workaround would be to put an if-statement around plugin-specific remaps that checks whether that plugin has been activated.

How can I do this with VimPlug? Does VimPlug store a list somewhere?

---

**Edit**, to clarify things: I need an actual list or a string, not the panel that `:PlugStatus` brings up. For example: with [a list](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/35.html) of activated plugins, any mappings specific to the plugin `plugin_name` would be wrapped in this if statement:

```
if index(plugin_list, 'plugin_name') != -1
  <special maps here>
endif
```

The `index` command returns `-1` if the string `'plugin_name'` is not contained in the list `plugin_list`.

Comment: Do you mean `:PlugStatus`?

Comment: See [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14143/7070) and [here](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/issues/146).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all plugs from `g:plugs_order` list or `g:plugs` dict.
`g:plugs`'s value also contain useful config infomation about the plug. Like `dir` where the plug is installed.

So, you can use:

```
if has_key(g:plugs, "name")
    " do something
endif
```

to check and do something when the plug exist.